# How to truncate the beginning of a String

Tags: vba, string

Is there a way to truncate the beginning of a string only that has certain number of "0"? How do I remove (some) leading zeros?

Database values looks like this:

```
|col_id|
|------|
|000001|
|01    |
|000c00|
```

I would like to be able to; First row get; 1, Second row; 01, Third row 0c00

I have tried with `string.TrimStart("0"c)` however I need to be able to truncate the string dynamically.

Comment: You need to provide more context. We don't even know what applicatin this is running in, so no idea what is meant by "database". Provide the code you've tried and explain *how* it's not working. You can use the [edit] link under the question to add relevant information directly to the question. Please do *not* include it in a comment.

Comment: Also, please explain the logic of the results you describe. When are zeros retained and when removed? The first result does not match the logic of the second and third results.

Answer (score 0):

Old School: Use the Mid function run over the character and implement some logic even it makes some afford. Programming is not all the time just copy things from the web ;)

```
Function data_wash(ByVal h As String) As String
Dim t As String
Dim i As Long

    A="0123456789.-"'allowed chars
    For i = 1 To Len(h)
        c = Mid(h, i, 1)
        If InStr(A, c) > 0 Then
            OUT = OUT & t
        Else
            OUT = OUT & " "
        End If
    Next

data_wash = OUT
End Function
```